# What's an easy way to obtain the current svn revision in a c++ visual studio application

Tags: c++, svn

Is there any easy way to access the SVN repository revision number and store it in a c++ string in a c++ visual studio application?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have tortoise SVN you can use SubWCRev.exe

Create a file called:

RevisionInfo.tmpl

```
int SvnRevision = $WCREV$;
```

Then execute this command:

```
SubWCRev.exe . RevisionInfo.tmpl RevisionInfo.cpp
```

It will create a file ReivisonInfo.cpp with your revision number as follows:

```
int SvnRevision = 5000;
```

From your other files just do something like:

extern int SvnRevision; to access the global variable from within that file.

You could also use [SvnRev](http://www.compuphase.com/svnrev.htm)